# Webbrowser downloadedcompleted - how to call event when page into control is loaded?

Tags: c#, browser

I have WebBrowser control on form which is displayed before application start. On form with WebBrowser I have button Close to close this form. I use this form to show ad. Button close is disabled. I want to make it enabled when ad is load complited. I use downloadCompleted event but I noticed that this event is called when ad is downloaded. But ad is swf file and a litle time is taken to show this ad in webbrowser, and user can faster close this form before ad will show.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start a timer when the DownloadCompleted event is fired, and have the timer.Elapsed event enable the button?  That would give you some extra time for the swf file to load and render before enabling the close button.

By the way, you don't way what kind of app you are targeting - WinForms / WPF / Silverlight / Phone - these may all have slight differences for the actual implementation, but the above paradigm should work...